# How to point different domains to the same site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, multisite

I've found myself in a situation where I have to use different domains for the same site. 
It's a multilingual website that uses the path for the language so I have something like:

```
mysite.com/en
mysite.com/es
mysite.com/fr
mysite.com/ru
```

What I need is something like

```
mysite.com/en
misitio.es/es
monsite.fr/fr
bladimir.ru/ru
```

It's an Apache server. We enabled domain aliases and if I enter `misitio.es` the server redirects the web browser to `mysite.com/es` but showing `misitio.es` in the url. 
What I would need is each domain to work on their own, not redirecting me, sharing all the content and source code. There should be no differences neither in files or in the database, and the htaccess should be configured to redirect each language (/es, /en, /fr, /ru) to its respective domain (*It's the last thing to do, we have not changed thw htaccess file yet).

I've found [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) for multisites in drupal, but it explains how to build a multisite from zero and my website is already in production, also, I'm not sure on how does it apply to my specific problem.

Is it possible to achieve what I need?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with "redirects to `mysite.com/es`, but showing `misitio.es` in the url"? If the browser still shows misitio.es, it isn't redirected.

Comment: @Miquel, can you paste the relevant (Rewrite) part of your current .htaccess

Comment: If i go to 'misitio.es' i will see the content that i would see in 'mysite.com/es' but in the web browser i only see 'misitio.es' (I don't see any other path or parameters in the url, just the domain). As long as I navigate in the same window I'll keep seeing 'misitio.es' in the navigation bar (alltough all the links pint to 'mysite.com/es/wathever'), but if i open a link in a new windo wor tab the domain will be 'mysite.com' again. I hope it clarifies what i mean.

Comment: *I'm not redirecting anything in the htaccess yet.

Comment: What happens, when you go to `misitio.es/somewhere/else`? Do you see the contents of `mysite.com/es/somewhere/else`?

Comment: "The requested URL /somewhere/else was not found on this server.
Apache Server at www.misitio.es Port 80"

Comment: So you cannot see any real content, only the home page?

Comment: I can see the content if I navigate through the links, since all they point to the original 'mysite.com/lang' url. (but as i said, as long as i dont change the window the domain shown in the navbar will be 'misitio.es' without parameters).

Comment: And you always see `misito.es`, no matter which link you follow?

Comment: Exactly. I think that the configuration we set for the server is not the proper one, but that's the point. I don't know how to make the apache server to point the different domains to the same folder with each one working independently of the other ones (I don't want a main domain since each domain will work for a single language).

Comment: I guess this is a CMS issue, if it is a problem at all, rather than an .htaccess problem. It looks like you already have a proper `DocumentRoot` set for each domain, which is what I would have suggested.

Comment: It's solved, It was a missconfiguration in Plesk. Thank you for your help.